# Understanding nested angular components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I was just going through the below angular code which is part of the nebular framework (its a library of essential UI components for angular 2 apps):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nb-layout-header-test',
  template: `
    <nb-layout>
      <nb-layout-header fixed>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ngx-admin</a>
      </nb-layout-header>
    </nb-layout>
`,
})
export class NbLayoutHeaderTestComponent {
}
```

The above lines of code can be seen [here](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/app/layout-test/layout-header-test.component.ts#L9).

Now i am not quite understanding what exactly is `<nb-layout>` and `<nb-layout-header fixed>` are these separate components that have been defined somewhere else and are being used in this particular component ?

I am new to angular and mostly have seen simplistic components that looks like below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'my-friends'
    template: `
        <h1>Hello from the {{ componentName }}!</h1>
        <div *ngFor="#f of friends">
            <h3>Name: {{ f.name }}</h3> 
            <h4>Age: {{ f.age }}</h4> 
        </div>
    `
})
```

Can somebody explain to me how exactly is that component constructed ?

Comment: https://akveo.github.io/nebular/#/docs/components/layout. Yes, these are nebular components.

Comment: I'd suggest you go back over the basics; see e.g. [the introduction of multiple components in the tour](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3).

Comment: Nizet thanks ... thats really helps ! @jonrsharpe thanks .. thats what i am trying to do now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are are separate components and are defined somewhere else like in your case you are using a selector named `nb-layout-header-test`. This means that you can use this component by just writing

```
<nb-layout-header-test>
```

anywhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks but i know that , i am looking for where is it defined .

Comment: ok, <nb-layout> and <nb-layout-header> are defined in src/framework/theme/components/layout/layout.component.ts